# What socket error do I get when TCP keep-alive breaks the connection?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a set of TCP sockets with keep-alive (interval 1 min), controlled by a [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)  loop (selecting for read).

- Will `select(2)` return an error if keep-alive timeout has happened for one of the sockets in the set?
- Which error will `read(2)` return?

Comment: If you are talking about async sockets selector than how do you expect it to select the socket which will be effectively dead by the time keepalive expires?

Comment: select() will return read notification and then recv() will return 0, indicating that the remote connection is closed

Comment: @strkol No, read doesn't return 0 unless the other end closes the connection. Here, no FIN was received. An error is returned instead (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `select()` itself does not return an error if an error is signalled for one of the sockets it is selecting for. [Indeed, the API can't indicate per-socket errors this way, because two different sockets could each acquire a pending error during a single call of `select()`. Which one would `select()` return?]
- After each iteration of the `select()` loop, you instead use the FD_ISSET macro to attempt a `read()` on each socket marked readable.
- Any time a socket has a pending error set, its read event (and write event) are signalled, and `select()` returns, allowing you to pick up timed-out errors due to keep-alive immediately. Note that select marking a socket for read does not indicate that there is data to read, only that an attempt to read will not block. If the socket has a pending error to retrieve, reading will not block. Both `read(2)` and `write(2)` first retrieve any pending error on the socket before even attempting to handle any data.

> A descriptor shall be considered ready for reading when a call to an input function with O_NONBLOCK clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully. (The function might return data, an end-of-file indication, or an error other than one indicating that it is blocked, and in each of these cases the descriptor shall be considered ready for reading.) [[POSIX:select()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)]
>
> Finally, what error is returned? Crucially, it depends on how the keepalive failed. You'll get `ETIMEDOUT` if the other end vanishes totally. If a packet delivery error occurs, you'll get that through instead (so if the keep-alive packet gets an ICMP error reply, like "host unreachable", you'll have `EHOSTUNREACH` delivered). [For more details on these cases, see Stevens, "Unix Network Programming, vol 1".]

Comment: In my case select is not returning success for read set. If it returns read set i will not have any problem as read would fail and i would know that the socket is dead. When keep-alive timeout happens on a socket, why will select return set for read ? The socket is not really ready for read.

Comment: Gajanan, I don't understand what you're saying. `select` does return having set the socket for read, and `read` does fail to inform you the socket is dead. That's exactly why `select` sets the socket readable: so that you know something has happened and can pick up the error. Finally, `select` is correct to mark the socket readable even when there's no data to read: the manual gives the more precise description, "select marks for read if read will not block". Returning an error is instant (won't block), so that fits the documentation (read it, please!).

Comment: 'Read does fail to inform you the socket is dead' contradicts the rest of your comment. Is that what you intended to say?

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the correction; I meant to say "read does *not* fail to inform you".

Comment: POSIX also says that "If a socket has a pending error, it shall be considered to have an exceptional condition pending", but Linux doesn't put such sockets into errfds.

Answer (score 1):

`select()` sets a bit in the `FDSET`  that indicates which socket has triggered.  Use [FD_ISSET](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpc2/cpp_fd_isset.html) macro to determine which socket asked for service.