# How to implement TCP SO_KEEPALIVE in C on LINUX (Ubuntu)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, tcp

I am trying to implement the TCP SO_KEEPALIVE to close and reconnect my connection when a keep alive message does not receive a response. My problem is that I have not had any luck with this and I think (hope) it is because I am not implementing it right. Below is a example of how I am implementing this.

```
//var to re-set socket's timeout value
struct timeval timeout; 

//creates a variable for KEEPALIVE's optval parm
 int optval; 

//creates a variable for KEEPALIVE's optlen parm
   socklen_t optlen = sizeof(optval); 

// sets KEEPALIVE parms
optval = 1;
optlen = sizeof(optval);

// turns on KEEPALIVE property on socket
if (setsockopt (Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, optlen) < 0)
    {
        CloseSocket(Socket, 0);
        connect(Socket);

    }
```

Comment: Closing and then connecting the closed socket on failure of setsockopt() is senseless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is only showing you setting the socket option then immediately closing and reopening it. Setting the socket option will not tell you that the keepalive has failed. You'll get that as a result of checking the socket (with a read, write, poll/select etc.) Setting the option merely turns on the keep-alive sending & checking. Look for ETIMEDOUT as the errno.

Comment: I have been reading http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/ on how TCP SO_KEEPALIVE works and I am unsure as to how I am supposed to do a check it has failed. Thank you for your timely response.

Comment: Yeah, that doc doesn't tell you how to check for when a keepalive fails, it's just showing how to turn it on and check that it has been successfully turned on. If it fails you'll get an error returned when you try and read/write or poll on the socket.

Comment: ok, could you possibly point me in the right direction to a place that defines how you can check it the TCP SO_KEEPALIVE has failed? Thank you

Comment: I always point everyone to the same place for these sorts of things! There's a book by W. Richard Stevens called "Unix Network Programming" that is the total bible for network programming, it's genuinely worth the money. The bit you need is here though: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=w+richard+stevens+keepalive&source=bl&ots=Kr5GPncnRs&sig=aVrYHuwl3jEXq1TwKdU-wWiDCJY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tecHUZW4N9C20QWRiYCIBQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=w%20richard%20stevens%20keepalive&f=false

Comment: Thank you sir for your help, I will have to procure that book!

Comment: I posted the info from that book in duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824231/what-socket-error-do-i-get-when-tcp-keep-alive-breaks-the-connection

Answer (score 1):

If TCP KEEPALIVE fails you get an error in the next read or write to the socket after the detection, typically ECONNRESET. It isn't distinguishable as a KEEPALIVE failure specifically, just a general I/O error, which is what it is, really.

Comment: will that error on the next receive(read) be a -1 or 0? Thank you

Comment: nvm, don't need to know that.