# send is not sensing socket pending errors

Tags: sockets, tcp

My TCP client implements a keepalive function with `tcp_keepalive_interval = 10s`, `tcp_keepalive_time = 1s` and `tcp_keepalive_probes = 10`.

But the `send` function is not picking any error after connection has been broken for more than 20s. Ideally with keepalive enabled, after 20s (`keepalive_interval + keepalive_probes*keepalive_time`) `E_TIMEDOUT` should be added to socket pending errors.

> As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824231/what-socket-error-do-i-get-when-tcp-keep-alive-breaks-the-connection) answer says,
>
> "Both read(2) and write(2) first retrieve any pending error on the
>   socket before even attempting to handle any data."

The send should pick `E_TIMEDOUT` or any socket error when connection is closed by keepalive but it is not happening in below code.

```
    int sockfd = -1;
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) {
        cerr<<"ERROR: Failed to obtain Socket Descriptor!"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //setting keepalive
    int optval;
    socklen_t optlen = sizeof(optval);

    //setting keepalive
    optval = 1;
    optlen = sizeof(optval);
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, optlen) < 0) {
        cerr<<"set keepalive failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //setting tcp_keepalive_intvl
    optval = 10;
    optlen = sizeof(optval);
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &optval, optlen) < 0) {
        cerr<<"set tcp_keepalive_interval failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //setting tcp_keepalive_time
    optval = 1;
    optlen = sizeof(optval);
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &optval, optlen) < 0) {
        cerr<<"set tcp_keepalive_time failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //setting tcp_keepalive_probes
    optval = 10;
    optlen = sizeof(optval);
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &optval, optlen) < 0) {
        cerr<<"set tcp_keepalive_probe failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;
    remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote_addr.sin_port = htons(#port_no);
    remote_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(#ip_addr);
    memset(&remote_addr.sin_zero, 0, 8);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        cerr<<"Connect failed with ERRORNO "<<errno<<endl;
        return -1;
    } else {
        cout<<"TcpClient.cpp connected to server"<<endl;
    }
    while(1) {
        char data[20] = "hi hello";
        int ret = -1;
        if((ret = send(sockfd, data, 20, 0)) < 0) {
            cerr<<"TcpClient.cpp:- failed to send_data, ERROR CODE: "<<errno<<endl;
            return -1;
        } else if (ret == 0) {
            cout<<"send returns 0"<<endl;
        } else {
            cout<<"data sent"<<endl;
        }        
        sleep(1);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
```

I tested this code on a linux machine with gcc compiler. 
Note: I tried the same code with `recv` and it picked `E_TIMEDOUT` error neatly.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't waited long enough. From http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html:

```
tcp_keepalive_time

    the interval between the last data packet sent (simple ACKs are not considered data) and the first keepalive probe; after the connection is marked to need keepalive, this counter is not used any further 

tcp_keepalive_intvl

    the interval between subsequential keepalive probes, regardless of what the connection has exchanged in the meantime 

tcp_keepalive_probes

    the number of unacknowledged probes to send before considering the connection dead and notifying the application layer
```

So with your values of (10, 10, 10), the keepalives will not start until 10 seconds after the last data was received from the peer. Then 10 probes, each separated by 10 seconds will need to be unacknowledged before the connection is declared dead.

Comment: Sorry for wrongly mentioning tcp_keepalive_time as 10s instead of 1s. I have edited the question. Actually my understanding of keepalive parameters are correct but there is something else which i am missing.